# Cutting the image in jigsaw shapes in android

Tags: android, image-processing

I want to know how to cut an image in jigsaw form in android at run time. What i actually want is user can enter any image and then made puzzle of it.

Any API or method for doing this in android ?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [this method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) in Bitmap to cut it into a new BitMap of specified width and height pixels
starting from specified pixel location of x and y

```
public static Bitmap createBitmap (Bitmap source, 
                                   int x, 
                                   int y, int width, int height)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your puzzle piece is square, you can use [createBitmap()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) function.

> Returns an immutable bitmap from the specified subset of the source
>   bitmap. The new bitmap may be the same object as source, or a copy may
>   have been made. It is initialized with the same density as the
>   original bitmap.